# Database errors when deleting channel fields and second site with Multisite Manager

Tags: channel, database, multi-site-manager

I'm using ExpressionEngine 2.5.2.

I recently added a second site using Multisite Manager on my local environment, staging environment, and production environment. The installation is complete and I have my second templates working correctly. I am only working on my local set up, but as soon as I have this up and running without errors, I will be moving all of my changes over to my staging site, then production site. Locally, when I try to add new channels field groups to my second site within my ExpressionEngine control pannel, my newly created channel field groups are automatically showing the channel fields from my primary site. I cannot delete the old channel fields, because I am receiving the following database error(s):

> Error Number: 1091
>
> Can't DROP 'field_id_176'; check that column/key exists
>
> ALTER TABLE exp_channel_data DROP field_id_176
>
> Filename: libraries/api/Api_channel_fields.php
>
> Line Number: 434

This error is different depending on the channel field I try to delete. It will vary by listing a different database entry that it cannot drop (i.e . 'field_id_176,' 'field_id_178,' etc.)

If I manually delete those fields in my database, it removes them from my second site, but it also removes them from my primary site. Obviously this is a problem because I am racking up too many fields which is very confusing.

I also cannot delete the second site, because it gives me the same database errors. When I try to hook up a third site, it does not recognize the folder with my templates in it and the Template Manager page shows up with no templates  or template groups (the folders exist locally and all of my paths to the appropriate directories are correct).

I do not have this problem on my staging or production server, but I cannot get much work done locally and I'm in a time crunch!! Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to problem solve the exact issue on my computer, however (luckily!) we had a second copy running without errors on a computer. I ended copying all of those files onto my machine, then importing that database and all is working fine now.